# NodeJS Express, adding transaction ids

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Folks,
  Trying to set a transaction id for each api call.  The following works:

```
var cls = require('continuation-local-storage');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var namespace = cls.createNamespace('foo');

var tokenMiddleware = function tokenMiddleware(req, res, next){

        namespace.bindEmitter(req);
        namespace.bindEmitter(res);
        namespace.run(function() {
            namespace.set('tid', tid);
            next();
        });

};
```

Now, when I try adding additional information (returned from mongo), it loses context:

```
var cls = require('continuation-local-storage');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var namespace = cls.createNamespace('foo');

var tokenMiddleware = function tokenMiddleware(req, res, next){

    mongo.fetchId(authId, function (result) {

                namespace.bindEmitter(req);
                namespace.bindEmitter(res);
                namespace.run(function() {
                    namespace.set('tid', tid);
                    namespace.set('somethingfromDB',result.something);
                    next();
                });

    });
};
```

the transaction id is not available further down, its undefined...  How come does the first example work, and the second one does not?

What am I doing wrong?  I suspect the problem has to do something with the next() context.  Express v4.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is tid defined?

Comment: Does `result` object indeed have the `something` property?

Comment: The comments here suggest that you maybe should have posted a complete code example. I mean with a minimal express / mongo setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar problem using express. As far as I can tell, the mongo module overwrites the request and response functions. Once you are inside the database call you will find that these objects are no longer what you expect them to be. My solution was to split this into 2 separate functions, which allows you to explicitly pass them to the db function.

```
var tokenMiddleware = function tokenMiddleware(req, res, next){

    var callDB = function (req, res, namespace) {
        mongo.fetchId(authId, function (result) {

            namespace.bindEmitter(req);
            namespace.bindEmitter(res);
            namespace.run(function() {
                namespace.set('tid', tid);
                namespace.set('somethingfromDB',result.something);
                next();
            });
        });
    });
    callDB(req, res, namespace)
};
```

Comment: How would mongo overwrite the local variables of that function?

Comment: I'm not totally sure but I believe it has to do with the infamous 'this', and what it references. Within the mongo function set has a totally different meaning than within the express function. While in the mongo call, this would be the mongo db object, and therefore set() is a different function, and the response object can't have it called on it. By passing in the object you are sending it's prototype functions along with, thereby maintaining a set() function that can be called on it.

Comment: when using `mongoose` i do NOT see this issue at all.  Your answer is most likely correct.  When I verify, will accept.  THANK YOU!

Comment: I have not used mongoose, only mongodb, but last night I woke up with a slightly more accurate explanation. Both the middleware and mongodb call return a stream object. The res object is a writeable stream, and the req object is a readable stream. In the same vein, the mongodb call returns a readable stream. In order to do this without passing the streams to your mongo function, you could pipe the db call to the res stream and write to it using the through module. https://www.npmjs.org/package/through

Answer (score -1):

Try setting SomethingfromDB in a promise.
Refer 
https://www.promisejs.org/
or try assigning the tid after somethingfromdb is set

```
var cls = require('continuation-local-storage');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var namespace = cls.createNamespace('foo');

var tokenMiddleware = function tokenMiddleware(req, res, next){

mongo.fetchId(authId, function (result) {

            namespace.bindEmitter(req);
            namespace.bindEmitter(res);
            namespace.run(function() {

                namespace.set('somethingfromDB',result.something);
                    namespace.set('tid', tid);
                next();
            });

});
};
```

hope this helps

Comment: i said you can use promises

Comment: How? Why would they help? What exactly did you change in the code, it looks very much like the snippet that the OP posted?